# Photo Dimensions wrong in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, stream

I have a picture here with a width of 2008px. If I read this picture with WPF using this code:

```
            byte[] baSource = File.ReadAllBytes(strFileName);
        using (Stream streamPhoto = new MemoryStream(baSource))
        {
            BitmapFrame bfPhoto = ReadBitmapFrame(streamPhoto);
            Console.WriteLine(bfPhoto.Width);       }
```

It tells me the picture is 52607,9686523093px width .. I don't understand why.
(same for the heigtht)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapframe.aspx you will see that the `Width` property "Gets the width of the bitmap in device-independent units (1/96th inch per unit)." What you want is `PixelWidth`: "Gets the width of the bitmap in pixels."